# cordova 2.7 with phonegap-facebook-plugin -build errors in ConnectPLugin.java

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using cordova 2.7 for one of my android development project. I followed all the steps on 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin
for android installation of the plugin.

My problem is ConnectPLugin.java class extends from PLugin class which should be part of org.apache.cordova.api.* library.

But plugin class is deprecated from cordova long back (http://wiki.apache.org/cordova/DeprecationPolicy) in v 2.3 of the cordova framework.

The new CordovaPlugin class replaces PLugin class in the newer frameworks but some functions are not supported (success and error).

So in effect i cannot compile my project because of these build errors. Please help

Any help is appreciated. I am new to android development so if I am making any obvious mistake please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

`ConnectPLugin` or `ConnectPlugin`?

As you mentioned, `Plugin` class is deprecated from phonegap 2.7, it has been renamed to `CordovaPlugin`. :(

See https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commit/4864d52966a317238ab48a84bbf12fe53240d3e3 and some guy's comment https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commit/4864d52966a317238ab48a84bbf12fe53240d3e3#commitcomment-3217047 bellow. :)

But, from a bit earlier commit https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/commit/6e6e0275add95a8caed647bdf862aded138bfecd you can see how to fix your plugin.

Hint, replace problematic `success(progressResult, callbackId)` with `callbackContext.sendPluginResult(progressResult)`. You should be able to see all needed changes in the commit above. E.g. replacing parameter `String callbackId` with `CallbackContext callbackContext`, etc.

In shortest, `Plugin` was inheriting `CordovaPlugin` for some time and implementing few additional functions on which third party (facebook) plugins were relying. Now you have to implement them in you plugin now, since `Plugin` class is removed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [fork on github](https://github.com/Raffaello/phonegap-facebook-plugin) updating the plugin to be compatible with 2.7, and saving you doing all these mentioned changes manually.